# How do I find a component, deferring to the children or parent if there is none?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to create a function in C# in Unity that will take a GameObject and a Component, and return an attached Component from the base, child, or parent elements.

If the target GameObject does not contain the requested Component, I wish to look to any children. If there are no children, or the children do not contain the requested Component, I wish to look to the parent.

How do I find a component, deferring to the the children or parent if there is none?

Comment: Please note the large changes I have made to your question. It is unwise to simply answer a question with "sorry guys, it actually works"; if your original code *did* work, your question is technically off-topic for not providing code to reproduce the problem. Given that you mentioned intention to leave the script here, for other users, I have reformed your initial question into a self-answered question and answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I've never been in this particular situation with a question before, but I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought of making an extension method, as you proposed. But took consideration of the priority, I didn't know about **GetComponentInParent**, but it does internally what I am suggesting here, which is looking recursively upwards, just in case you wanted to know how that method works.

What you could take from here is passing an enumerator value indicating the desired priority, since maybe you want to first look for children, then for parents, or viceversa.

```
public enum SearchPriority
{
    Parents,
    Children
}

public static class TransformExtensions
{
    public static T GetComponentsDepthSearch<T>(this UnityEngine.Component _object SearchPriority _priority = SearchPriority.Children) where T : UnityEngine.Component
    {
        T component = _object.GetComponent<T>();
        if(component != null) return component;
        else
        {
            switch(_priority)
            {
                case SearchPriority.Parents:
                {
                    Transform current = _object.transform.parent;

                    while(current != null)
                    {
                        component = current.GetComponent<T>();
                        if(component != null) return component;
                        else current = current.parent;
                    }
                }
                break;

                case SearchPriority.Children:
                {
                    foreach(Transform child in _object.transform)
                    {
                        component = child.GetComponent<T>();
                        if(component != null) return component;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return component;
    }
}
```

Here I am using the keyword **this** so the method is extended (also, since a Component extends the method, any component can access that method), and also constrains, so the expected value is from UnityEngine's **Component**.

**NOTE:** If you wanted to get a component implementing a certain interface, passing that interface type, maybe the constrain would be good to avoid.

Hope it adds something more to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have created said functionality with the following static method:

```
public static T GetCombatComponent<T>(GameObject go)
{
    T _ret;
    _ret = go.GetComponent<T>();

    if (_ret == null)
    {
        _ret = go.GetComponentInChildren<T>();
    }

    if (_ret == null)
    {
        _ret = go.GetComponentInParent<T>();
    }

    return _ret;
}
```

This appears to work, and can be called as follows:

```
DamageListener _dl = CombatMethods.GetCombatComponent<DamageListener>(c.gameObject);
```

Comment: I can personally confirm that this mostly works. If there is no Component of type `T` in the target, children *or* parent, returning `_ret` immediately results in a fatal `NullReferenceException` (for obvious reasons).

Comment: Ah good call - I should wrap this in a try() and catch the exception properly.

Comment: You can start with `GetComponentInChildren` and save one if clause - this method already returns the component on the current GameObject if there is one.

Comment: @DMGregory - that's good to know.  I didn't realize that was the case.  Thanks!